# upload_to based off foreign key value

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have an `Image` model. I want it to upload to a folder depending on which category the user chooses. For example if the user chooses the "apples" category I'd like it to upload to a media folder called "apples".

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=category)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a callable to the `category` that takes as parameters `self` and the `filename` of the original file.

You thus can define this as:

```
from os.path import join as osjoin

class Image(models.Model):

    def image_dir(self, filename):
        return osjoin(str(self.category), filename)

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_dir)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Note that here I assume that you have given the `Category` model a `__str__` method. You might however change `str(self.category)` to for example: `self.category.name` for example if the `Category` has a `name` field, and you want to use that.