# How can I access properties of a foreign key field in django?

Tags: django, orm

In my Django application, I have 2 models: `Product` and `Image`.

A product can have many images and an image can only belong to a single product.

I want to be able to create a sub-folder for the images of a product with the name of the product itself when images of a product are uploaded. So, in the `Image` model, I need to access the title of the `product`.

Here is my code:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True, allow_unicode=True)

class Image(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                                related_name='images')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=f'product_images/{product.title}/')
```

In the `Image` model, I have an `image` field which is of type `ImageField` in which I want to get the title of the `product`.

I get the following error:

> 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'title'

How can I access the title of the `product` inside the `Image` model?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [upload\_to based off foreign key value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58884961/upload-to-based-off-foreign-key-value)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately no this answer doesn't help me. Because the image_dir(self, filename) method is created and it's only referenced (not invoked) in the ImageField() attribute of the class and thus the dir name will become the reference address to the method in memory. I'm a beginner in django world and maybe this is why I can't understand this answer! I also can't understand what "filename" parameter is in the image_dir(self, filename) method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because this line:

```py
image = models.ImageField(upload_to=f'product_images/{product.title}/')
```

Is evaluated when the model is defined, and in that context 'product.title' doesn't yet make sense: it only makes sense when an instance of the class is created with an associated product.

To get around this, use a helper function like `get_upload_to` and pass it as the argument to the `upload_to` parameter, as below:

```py
def get_upload_to(instance, filename):
    return f'product_images/{instance.product.title}/{filename}'

class Image(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='images')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_to)
```

This method works because when the `get_upload_to` method is called by Django, it will automatically pass both the instance and filename variables to it (see official docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to )

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and the explanation! Works great!

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Please do accept as correct answer if it worked correctly, always appreciated and helps boost the algo :D